# In Objective-c autoReleased Objects are released if no pointer points to them anymore?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

Just from Curiosity... If I alter a pointer to point to an other autoreleased instance, the previous autoreleased instance that the pointer was pointing to, is autoreleased normally ? For example ...

```
NSString pStr* = [NSString stringWithString:@"instance One"];
// do sth with pStr
pStr = [NSString stringWithString:@"Instance two"];
// do sth else with pStr
```

Are Both of the instances autoreleased ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Lifecycle of objects doesn't really depend on which variables point to them (unlike environments with garbage-collection). That's why it's possible to have variable pointing to deallocated object or have memory leaks: objects retained forever with no references to them.

Lifecycle depends on how objects are created and how you use `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` methods.

It's explained in more details in Cocoa [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).